# Codeigniter Pagination 3.0.4 Sort Directories And Files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a working file manager with codeIgniter 3.0.4 pagination library.

I am trying to make sure it displays the directory's first and then files in the pagination.

Currently the codeigniter pagination sorts the directories and files all by name.

Question with codeigniter pagination how can I make sure it all ways displays the directories first. Then sorts out the files.

```
<?php

class Filemanager extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    public function index($results = NULL) {    
        $data['title'] = 'File Manager';

        $this_input_get_directory = $this->input->get('directory');

        if (isset($this_input_get_directory)) {
            $directory = scandir(FCPATH . 'images/catalog/' . $this_input_get_directory . '/', 1);
        } else {
            $directory = scandir(FCPATH . 'images/catalog/', 1);
        }

        $files = array_diff($directory, array('.', '..'));
        $files_limit = 3;
        $input_get_per_page = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $input_get_per_page += $files_limit;

        $config['base_url'] = base_url('filemanager');
        $config['total_rows'] = count($files);
        $config['per_page'] = $files_limit;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
        $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['images'] = array();

        foreach ($files as $file => $value) {

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this_input_get_directory)) {
                $url .= $this_input_get_directory . '/';
            } else {
                $url .= '';
            }  

            if ($file < $input_get_per_page && $file >= $input_get_per_page - $files_limit) {

                if (is_dir(FCPATH . 'images/catalog/' . $value)) {

                    $data['images'][] = array(
                        'thumb' => '',
                        'type' => 'directory',
                        'href' => site_url('filemanager') . '?directory='. $url . $value,
                        'name' => $value
                    );  

                } elseif (is_file(FCPATH . 'images/catalog/' . $url . $value)) {

                    $data['images'][] = array(
                        'thumb' => $this->resize($value, 100, 100),
                        'type' => 'image',
                        'name' => $value
                    );  
                }

            }
        }

        $this->load->view('template/common/filemanager_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved I have found some code from some where else that made it work for me. I have also used now array_reverse(); all working so far.

```
<?php

class Filemanager extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->helper('custom');
        define('DIR_IMAGE', FCPATH . 'images/');

    }

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = 'File Manager';

        if ($this->uri->segment(3)) {

            $this_input_get_directory = $this->uri->segment(2) . '/' . $this->uri->segment(3);

        } else {

            $this_input_get_directory = $this->uri->segment(2) . '/' . $this->uri->segment(3);

        }

        if (isset($this_input_get_directory)) {

            $directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this_input_get_directory), '/');

        } else {

            $directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';
        }

        // Get directories
        $directories = glob($directory . '/' . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

        if (!$directories) {
            $directories = array();
        }

        // Get files
        $files = array_reverse(glob($directory . '/' . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE));

        if (!$files) {
            $files = array();
        }

        // Merge directories and files
        $images = array_merge($directories, $files);

        $files_limit = 6;
        $input_get_per_page = $this->input->get('per_page');
        $input_get_per_page += $files_limit;

        $config['base_url'] = base_url('filemanager');
        $config['total_rows'] = count($images);
        $config['per_page'] = $files_limit;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
        $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['images'] = array();

        foreach ($images as $file => $value) {

            $filename = str_replace(FCPATH . 'images/', '', $value);

            $display_name = basename($filename);

            if ($file < $input_get_per_page && $file >= $input_get_per_page - $files_limit) {

                if (is_dir(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {

                    $data['images'][] = array(
                        'thumb' => '',
                        'type' => 'directory',
                        'path' => $value,
                        'name' => $display_name,
                        'href' => site_url('filemanager/' . $display_name)
                    );  

                } else if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {

                    $data['images'][] = array(
                        'thumb' => $this->resize($filename),
                        'type' => 'image',
                        'path' => $value,
                        'name' => $display_name
                    );  
                }

            }
        }

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this_input_get_directory)) {
            $pos = strrpos($this_input_get_directory, '/');

            if ($pos) {
                $url .= '?directory=' . urlencode(substr($this_input_get_directory, 0, $pos));
            }
        }

        $data['parent'] = base_url('filemanager' . $url);

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this_input_get_directory)) {
            $url .= '?directory=' . $this_input_get_directory;
        }

        $data['refresh'] = base_url('filemanager' . $url);

        $this->load->view('template/common/filemanager_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!$files) {$files = array();}` is an odd choice.  If the `$files` array is empty, declare `$files` as an empty array.

Comment: If `$this->uri->segment(3)` then `$this_input_get_directory = $this->uri->segment(2) . '/' . $this->uri->segment(3);` else do the same thing. ...Hmm.